# Why git checkout after git clone?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-checkout, git-clone

I am new to git. I understand git basics as well as development procedures using git, however there is one thing that confuses me.

Whenever I have to pull something from a git repo with multiple projects inside ([example](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline)), I see these instruction steps:

1. git clone xxx
2. cd xxx
3. git checkout yyy

This is a bit puzzling to me. As I already have the entire repo, why would I want to checkout the project I am interested in if I can just copy the folder and do whatever I like with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: I started this as a comment but it's long enough, and really can use some formatting, that I moved it to an answer.  It is a reply to your comment to Tim Beigeleisen:

> If you refer to my example link, checking out "stereo_image_proc" works but I can't see it being one of the branches, how come?

The reason `git checkout stereo_image_proc` does not complain (and seems not to do anything, at first blush) is that `git checkout` itself is really two *different* commands combined into one.  This is a feature, or misfeature in some people's opinion (including mine): `git checkout`'s argument can be a *branch name*, or a *path name*.

Specifically:

- `git checkout branch` asks Git to switch to, or sometimes even create and then switch to, a branch whose name you supply on the command line.

  Switching *to* a branch is a surprisingly complicated process, in the end, but it starts out simple enough: it changes Git's notion of `HEAD` so that you're on the named branch.  It has another *very* useful feature: before Git actually switches to (and/or creates) this branch, Git makes sure that this won't clobber any work you accidentally started on the *wrong* branch.
- `git checkout name1 name2 ... nameN`, on the other hand, asks Git to extract *particular files* from some *named or implied commit*.  This is often best written out as `git checkout -- file`, where the `--` tells Git that the name *should not* be treated as a *branch* name.  That is, suppose you have a *file* named `master` and you want to extract it: then `git checkout master` would not work because that's the *branch* named `master`, but you want the *file* named `master`.  So `git checkout -- master` tells Git: *not the branch, the file.*

  When you use this kind of `git checkout`, you're telling Git: *I know I started editing some file or files, but I have now decided that editing this file, or all of these files, was a mistake.  Put them all back the way they were, turning them back into a previous version of each file.*  For instance, suppose you have a file named `README.txt` and you started editing it and then realized that you should be creating a *new* documentation file.  You copy the new stuff you added to the new file, but now you want `README.txt` to go back to the way it was before you started editing it.  So you run `git checkout README.txt`, and that *wipes out your changes* to the file.

  But as far as Git is concerned, naming a *directory* here (or a folder if you prefer that term) means *every file in the directory, including any sub-directories recursively*.  Since `stereo_image_proc` is a directory, and is not a branch name, you are getting this second form of `git checkout`.

The bottom line is that `git checkout stereo_image_proc` tells Git to *wipe out any changes you made to any files within that directory*.  If you have not made any changes, well, no problem!  But if you have, this can be pretty disastrous.

Since `git checkout` *does* have these two modes—the safe *switch branches* mode, and the unsafe *clobber all my work* mode—you have to take note of which one you are invoking, every time you run `git checkout`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: he asked you, in his own first comment on your answer: *If you refer to my example link, checking out "stereo_image_proc" works but I can't see it being one of the branches, how come?*

Comment: You must have picked up on something I missed +1.

Comment: The more detailed answer I was looking for, excellent, really appreciate this!

Answer (score 6):

The first two steps just tell you to `git clone`, which will clone into some folder, and then to `cd` into that folder.  The third step would only be necessary if you *didn't* want to start working with the `master` or default branch of that repo.  Typically, after git cloning, the `master` branch would be selected by default.  So, if your instructions wanted you working on some other `yyy` branch, then the third step would make sense.

Running `git checkout yyy` will automatically create a local branch named `yyy` *if* there is a tracking branch in your repo by the same name.  In this case, it would also switch to that newly created local branch.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. If you refer to my example link, checking out "stereo_image_proc" works but I can't see it being one of the branches, how come?

Comment: Define `can't see.`  When you run `git branch -a`, are you saying you don't see a local/remote branch by the name `stereo_image_proc` ?

Comment: I do but not exactly "stereo_image_proc", I can see many versions of them. If you go to the github page and look in the "branches" tab you will see what I mean.

Comment: Then it sounds like the issue is you're not sure about your branch names.

Comment: Just to reiterate, there is no exact match for "stereo_image_proc" branch, on the other hand there is a branch called "stereo_image_proc_new_point_cloud". However, checking out "stereo_image_proc" works just fine.

Comment: This is a departure from your initial question.  You weren't asking about how to find the right branch.

Comment: My apologies, you have already answered my original question. Would you mind joining the chat for a brief moment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179528/discussion-between-hypomania-and-tim-biegeleisen).